# My Boss wants me to correct checks paid to us

Tags: fraud

I work for a county government. We process over 16,000 checks over about 2 months. I have an issue with some things we do. If someone writes a check out wrong, for example if he doesn't put the correct change in either the box or *Written Out*, we have to change it.

If someone writes in the box *285.00* but *Written* says *eighty five 00/100* my boss will make us write it in ourselves.

I don't feel comfortable changing someone else's check. I just want to find out whether this is legal to do or not.

Comment: I would say that if a mod could migrate the question over there, that'd be a win. Of course, it would also be ironic.

Comment: The Illinois Secretary of State's office specifically has on the application for driver's license renewal and vehicle title renewal that by submitting the application, the applicant specifically gives the State the authority to correct checks written incorrectly whether it is amount due, or payee, or date etc. Maybe the county office has something similar.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: IANAL but I'm not entirely certain that it's _possible_ to transfer that authority to a third party. Fraud is fraud even if you tell someone it's okay to defraud you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: True, but if a state government states this, chances are that state law permit such changes (in the circumstances described). And if it's legally permitted, it's by definition not fraud.

Comment: @MSalters -- administrative agencies quite often assume that they can do various things without knowing whether they are, in fact, legal. They are often wrong.

Comment: @MSalters: _"if a state government states this, chances are that state law permit such changes"_ I honestly think [that's a bit of a leap](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/appeal-to-authority). States do illegal things all the time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nonsense! The Illinois resident is _not_ telling the State of Illinois that is OK to defraud him/her, but that it is OK to correct the _applicant's_ mistake in writing the check. Now, whether the _bank_ will pay the check in which the words "two hundred" have _clearly_ been inserted, with appropriate proof-reader's marks before the "eighty-five and 00/100 dollars", is a different issue, but there is no _fraud_ involved: the payer _knows_ and has _agreed_ tp pay $285; it is just the payer's screw-up in forgetting to write "two hundred" preceding "eighty-five"etc.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: It's not "not fraud" to alter a cheque just because you can blame the payer for screwing up and writing something they did not mean on it. That is a very slippery slope. What I don't know (as explored above) is whether it is legally possible to transfer cheque-altering authority to the recipient (and thus make this "not fraud" by rights). It may still be a crime to alter a cheque even if the sender says "yes you can do this to my cheques" - I just don't know. OP should find out!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit could you detail a situation where this could lead to trouble? “Slippery slope” is not generally good enough reason for worry unless there is a specific & clear path to worry about.

Comment: As a practical matter, a county government employee is very likely unionized in a county processing that many checks, so raising a grievance through the union about the practice may be the best course of action.

Answer (score 29):

On a check, if the two amounts do not match, the written out amount should be considered correct.  [Section 3.114](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/3/3-114) of the Uniform Commercial Code states that:

> If an instrument contains contradictory terms, typewritten terms prevail over printed terms, handwritten terms prevail over both, and words prevail over numbers.

So, you simply accept the check for the written out amount.  **DO NOT** make changes to the document because that is fraudulent.  If the amounts do not agree, you can't pick which one you want to use - you must use the written amount.  If the written amount is incorrect, your only choice is to reject the check or accept it for the written amount (and bill for or refund the difference).

Comment: The UCC is irrelevant unless in a jurisdiction that has chosen to make it their law.  OP did not even state his/her country.

Comment: @WGroleau, Good point about not knowing OPs exact situation. The UCC was just one source I could find, but this rule is widely adopted and is good advice for others that come across checks that have mismatched amounts.  Of course a "government agency" or business owner should absolutely check the laws in their specific area.

Comment: 'county government' is a strong indicator or US or UK. Spelling of the word 'check' indicates US. Not 100%, but pretty safe.

Comment: @Jeutnarg no one in the uk refers to county government and in the uk a county is similar to a state  a parish would be the closest the UK has to an American county

Comment: @Neuromancer - I suppose I should have said Commonwealth. I do believe that Canada has counties that are similar to US counties (not in all provinces, but in more than a few)

Comment: @Neuromancer, how can you say a UK county is similar to a state and also say no one talks about county government. A state government is very important. It seems that UK counties are not similar to states.

Comment: @WGroleau, On the English web, default goes to US. Although the answerer should state the location too.

Answer (score 27):

**IANAL, I would seek legal advice from a legal professional.**
That being said. The proper way to handle someone miswriting information on a check is to reject the check and return it to the originator. Altering a check issued by someone else is a crime (potentially a felony, based on the sum of money involved), and you have every right to refuse to do it. I would **STRONGLY** suggest you document what's going on before saying anything though.